# Servlet Asynchronous questions and error

Tags: multithreading, servlets, asynchronous

Just started to learn Servlets and JSP and I tried to implemented according Asynchronous Servlets according to this guideness: https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/how-to-use-asynchronous-servlets-to-improve-performance

I have two questions about the subject:

1. I didn't understanding why Asynchronous Servlets should be faster. According to his example, instant of getting block by the server threads you are getting block by the application threads.
2. I tried to implemented his example, But when I run the Asynchronous Servlet I'm getting the annoying HTTP Status 500 error.
   `The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request`. 
   I have no idea why its not working, I'm not even sure how to start debugging it.

P.S. I thought it would be easier just to past here the URL because its almost the same as my code. But if you guys need I will pass the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Asynch Servlet (AS) is not faster.  It has more overheads than the normal servlet route.  Its main goal is to improve the WebContainer (WC) 's threads usage.

There are limited number of threads configured in the WC's thread-pool to serve the requests.  When requests are taking too long (for example, pending for data generation from database) to complete and the application server is under load, the WC will stop serving any new request until its thread is available (i.e previous request is completed thus free up a WC's thread).

This is where the AS coming in.  So instead of waiting, AS can be spin-off on a different thread (workload management threads...).  That allows the original servlet to be completed and thus release the WC's thread back to the pool in order to serve the next request.